# 420 <s>Blaze</s> Golf It

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, date

This is a pretty simple challenge, but (I hope) a fun one.

## Task

If right now either the month is `4` and the day is `20`, the hour (on a 12 hour clock) is `4` and the minute is `20`, or the minute is `4` and the second is `20`, print this ascii art:

```
                        .
                       .:.
                       :|:
                      .:|:.
                      ::|::
       :.             ::|::             .:
       :|:.          .::|::.          .:|:
       ::|:.         :::|:::         .:|:;
       `::|:.        :::|:::        .:|::'
        ::|::.       :::|:::       .::|:;
        `::|::.      :::|:::      .::|::'
         :::|::.     :::|:::     .::|::;
         `:::|::.    :::|:::    .::|::;'
`::.      `:::|::.   :::|:::   .::|::;'     .:;'
 `:::..    `;::|::.  :::|:::  .::|:::    ::::;
   `:::::.    ':|::. :::|::: .::|:'   ,::::;'
     `:::::.    ':|:::::|:::::|:'   :::::;'
       `:::::.:::::|::::|::::|::::.,:::;'
          ':::::::::|:::|:::|:::::::;:'
             ':::::::|::|::|:::::::''
                  `::::::::::;'
                 .:;'' ::: ``::.
                      :':':
                        ;
```

You can have trailing spaces.

Otherwise, print the number of minutes and seconds left until the next such occasion in the format: `%d minutes and %d seconds left until your next hit.` with the time being minimized.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

*P.S. If this challenge is too inappropriate for this site, tell me and I'll change it.*

Comment: Aren't you, like, in the first half of high school? :P

Comment: Also, does 4:00 PM (on an otherwise nonprint-y time) count as print-y because of the 4 or nonprint-y because it's also 16:00 hours?

Comment: I'd be more worried about it being a dupe, I feel like two halves of old challenges (the various timing ones and the various kgc ones) doesn't really make this a very interesting challenge, but I'm not really sure what I would close it as a dupe of (or if it's even correct to do that...).

Comment: @ANerd-I printy, I'll edit that in.

Comment: I was looking at this image and wondering if some sort of custom run-length encoding would be viable for golfing the output, or if there's a better solution?

Comment: Including ``\n .:;'`|`` that's 8 characters so the RLE would only need 3 bits to represent each character.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake on one line, where the central `|` does not line up with the centreline of the leaf. Correcting it by removing 4 `.` from the left and adding 4 spaces on the right I get `[   \:::::.    ':|::. :::|::: .::|:'   ,::::;']` Is this apparent error intentional? (backtick replaced by backslash)

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I honestly have no clue, I got this leaf from online. Do you want to edit it?

Comment: As there are no answers yet, I've gone ahead and edited. It makes it more symmetrical (though not perfectly symmetrical) which should be easier to golf.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt cool thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 371 bytes

This source contains non-printable bytes, so it is presented as a hexdump that can be decoded with `xxd -r`.

```
00000000: efbb bf66 726f 6d20 7469 6d65 2069 6d70  ...from time imp
00000010: 6f72 742a 0a74 3d74 696d 6528 290a 693d  ort*.t=time().i=
00000020: 300a 7768 696c 6527 3034 3a32 3027 6e6f  0.while'04:20'no
00000030: 7420 696e 2073 7472 6674 696d 6528 2725  t in strftime('%
00000040: 6d3a 2564 2572 272c 6c6f 6361 6c74 696d  m:%d%r',localtim
00000050: 6528 742b 6929 293a 692b 3d31 0a70 7269  e(t+i)):i+=1.pri
00000060: 6e74 5b22 7801 74cd c701 c430 0844 d1bb  nt["x.t....0.D..
00000070: aaf0 cd99 0286 6654 887a dfa0 f41d 7136  ......fT.z....q6
00000080: 8f61 7829 0b6f 5c72 bdb6 9414 de86 d2eb  .ax).o\r........
00000090: 9894 d4e7 64f7 de39 099a 8ed8 32b5 d34a  ....d..9....2..J
000000a0: e8c9 2a53 9da4 371a b1d0 a3d4 18e8 b212  ..*S..7.........
000000b0: 5a25 a139 158a ac90 4cba 7692 4007 c62e  Z%.9....L.v.@...
000000c0: 81b8 31c4 9682 04e2 6ab8 8f21 3bb3 3ce1  ..1.....j..!;.<.
000000d0: 7582 0163 8524 79a8 c175 cb58 7ce5 45ff  u..c.$y..u.X|.E.
000000e0: b3b7 8cc7 bfbe fbaa 9b95 b068 1837 db90  ...........h.7..
000000f0: a546 b54a 5cb9 5c38 6801 0936 a2a8 a85e  .F.J\.\8h..6...^
00000100: 6ca3 4c3e 8e83 a4ef 1412 12ac 7027 7075  l.L>........p'pu
00000110: 2084 ca61 026b 5c30 286e a1fe 222e 6465   ..a.k\0(n..".de
00000120: 636f 6465 2827 7a69 7027 292c 2725 6420  code('zip'),'%d 
00000130: 6d69 6e75 7465 7320 616e 6420 2564 2073  minutes and %d s
00000140: 6563 6f6e 6473 206c 6566 7420 756e 7469  econds left unti
00000150: 6c20 796f 7572 206e 6578 7420 6869 742e  l your next hit.
00000160: 2725 2869 2f36 302c 6925 3630 295d 5b69  '%(i/60,i%60)][i
00000170: 3e30 5d                                  >0]
```

Readable part:

```py
from time import*
t=time()
i=0
while'04:20'not in strftime('%m:%d%r',localtime(t+i)):i+=1
print["(ZLIB DATA)".decode('zip'),'%d minutes and %d seconds left until your next hit.'%(i/60,i%60)][i>0]
```

Comment: Oh whoops, I misread the code. I thought it continually looped and printed. Stupid tiny mobile screen.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 537 bytes

```js
alert((f=t=>new Date(Date.now()+t*1e3).toISOString().match`(T16|04)[-:]20`)(i=0)?"À\u0019\u0002û1!°?4\u0002ë14!°>C3\u0002=\u0001Ê34\u0003Ê1\u0002=4\u00011C3\u000114\u0002=C\u0013ð4\u0009\u001fCS\u0002m34\u0001>Ià14s\u0002>C3\u0001=IÐ1CS\u0002n34\u0013À4\u0009\u001c34s\u0002?I3\u0001;I°1C3%ð6I3\u0001:I 1C3ub3\u0001l4\u00134\u0009\u001934S\u0007\u001bS'`\u0011 V34\u0013\u00004\u0009\u001034\u0009:Z\u0002i³\u0001zC3\u00014\u00091Cs8Z'°6\u001b 74K³4\u00079['Ð6\u001b³4J£4\u001a8Y' yó4I4]s\u0002Ê7M34CÓw\u0002«6u\u00021u\u0007`6\u0013\u0002ëss#ÀY".replace(/./g,c=>(l=" .\n:|;`',0123456")[(n=c.charCodeAt())&15]+l[n>>4]).replace(/.\d+/g,c=>c[0].repeat(parseInt(c.slice(1),7)+3)):eval('for(;!f(++i););`${i/60|0} minutes and ${i%60|0} seconds left until your next hit.`'))
```

Uses the CP-1252 encoding.

*Note: All unreadables in this post are escaped with `\u00xx` so that the Stack Exchange system doesn't automatically remove them. They should be considered to have a size of one byte.*

### Explanation

Uses a run-length encoding scheme along with packing each character into 4 bits. The main logic of the code is 174 bytes and the leaf string (including decompression) is 364 bytes. Further details of the compression method are found below.

```js
alert((
  f=t=>                                   // f checks for 4:20 in a date
    new Date(Date.now()+t*1e3)            // get the date at now + t seconds
    .toISOString().match`(T16|04)[-:]20`  // find 4:20 in the ISO date string
)(i=0)?

  // Leaf decompression
  "À\u0019\u0002û1!°?4\u0002ë14!°>C3\u0002=\u0001Ê34\u0003Ê1\u0002=4\u00011C3\u000114\u0002=C\u0013ð4\u0009\u001fCS\u0002m34\u0001>Ià14s\u0002>C3\u0001=IÐ1CS\u0002n34\u0013À4\u0009\u001c34s\u0002?I3\u0001;I°1C3%ð6I3\u0001:I 1C3ub3\u0001l4\u00134\u0009\u001934S\u0007\u001bS'`\u0011 V34\u0013\u00004\u0009\u001034\u0009:Z\u0002i³\u0001zC3\u00014\u00091Cs8Z'°6\u001b 74K³4\u00079['Ð6\u001b³4J£4\u001a8Y' yó4I4]s\u0002Ê7M34CÓw\u0002«6u\u00021u\u0007`6\u0013\u0002ëss#ÀY"
  .replace(/./g,c=>                       // unpack each 4-bit character
    (l=" .\n:|;`',0123456")               // l = lookup table of characters
    [(n=c.charCodeAt())&15]+l[n>>4]       // return the two characters in the byte
  )
  .replace(/.\d+/g,c=>                    // run-length decoding
    c[0].repeat(parseInt(c.slice(1),7)+3) // repeat character n + 3 times (base-7)
  )

:eval(`                                   // eval just to allow a for loop here...
  for(;!f(++i););                         // check each second up until a match

  \`${i/60|0} minutes and ${i%60|0} seconds left until your next hit.\`
`))
```

### Compression Algorithms

#### No Compression, 911 bytes

This is the leaf string with no compression at all.

```js
`                        .
                       .:.
                       :|:
                      .:|:.
                      ::|::
       :.             ::|::             .:
       :|:.          .::|::.          .:|:
       ::|:.         :::|:::         .:|:;
       \`::|:.        :::|:::        .:|::'
        ::|::.       :::|:::       .::|:;
        \`::|::.      :::|:::      .::|::'
         :::|::.     :::|:::     .::|::;
         \`:::|::.    :::|:::    .::|::;'
\`::.      \`:::|::.   :::|:::   .::|::;'     .:;'
 \`:::..    \`;::|::.  :::|:::  .::|:::    ::::;
   \`:::::.    ':|::. :::|::: .::|:'   ,::::;'
     \`:::::.    ':|:::::|:::::|:'   :::::;'
       \`:::::.:::::|::::|::::|::::.,:::;'
          ':::::::::|:::|:::|:::::::;:'
             ':::::::|::|::|:::::::''
                  \`::::::::::;'
                 .:;'' ::: \`\`::.
                      :':':
                        ;`
```

#### Run-Length Encoding, 542 bytes

Since there are many consecutive repeated characters, run-length encoding improves the byte count significantly.

```js
` 21.
 20.:.
 20:|:
 19.:|:.
 19::|::
 4:. 10::|:: 10.:
 4:|:. 7.::|::. 7.:|:
 4::|:. 6:0|:0 6.:|:;
 4\`::|:. 5:0|:0 5.:|::'
 5::|::. 4:0|:0 4.::|:;
 5\`::|::. 3:0|:0 3.::|::'
 6:0|::. 2:0|:0 2.::|::;
 6\`:0|::. 1:0|:0 1.::|::;'
\`::. 3\`:0|::. 0:0|:0 0.::|::;' 2.:;'
 \`:0.. 1\`;::|::.  :0|:0  .::|:0 1:1;
 0\`:2. 1':|::. :0|:0 .::|:' 0,:1;'
 2\`:2. 1':|:2|:2|:' 0:2;'
 4\`:2.:2|:1|:1|:1.,:0;'
 7':6|:0|:0|:4;:'
 10':4|::|::|:4''
 15\`:7;'
 14.:;'' :0 \`\`::.
 19:':':
 21;`.replace(/.\d+/g,c=>c[0].repeat(+c.slice(1)+3))
```

Each character repeated 3 or more times is replaced with the character followed by a decimal number of `amount - 3`. The encoded string is generated with this code:

```js
uncompressed.replace(/(.)\1{2,}/g,c=>c[0]+(c.length-3))
```

#### 4-bit Packing + RLE, 364 bytes

There are 9 distinct characters in the original string, which means 4 is the minimum number of bits to represent each. Conveniently, this allows for exactly two character representations to fit into a single byte, enabling a simple (and golf-friendly) decompression algorithm to be used. On top of that, there are 7 characters left over, which allows base-7 run-length encoding to be used before packing. Putting each 4-bit index into the upper and lower nibbles of each compressed character means 2 characters are stored per byte, because the CP-1252 encoding encodes every character under code point 256 as a single byte.

```js
"À\u0019\u0002û1!°?4\u0002ë14!°>C3\u0002=\u0001Ê34\u0003Ê1\u0002=4\u00011C3\u000114\u0002=C\u0013ð4\u0009\u001fCS\u0002m34\u0001>Ià14s\u0002>C3\u0001=IÐ1CS\u0002n34\u0013À4\u0009\u001c34s\u0002?I3\u0001;I°1C3%ð6I3\u0001:I 1C3ub3\u0001l4\u00134\u0009\u001934S\u0007\u001bS'`\u0011 V34\u0013\u00004\u0009\u001034\u0009:Z\u0002i³\u0001zC3\u00014\u00091Cs8Z'°6\u001b 74K³4\u00079['Ð6\u001b³4J£4\u001a8Y' yó4I4]s\u0002Ê7M34CÓw\u0002«6u\u00021u\u0007`6\u0013\u0002ëss#ÀY"
.replace(/./g,c=>(l=" .\n:|;`',0123456")[(n=c.charCodeAt())&15]+l[n>>4])
.replace(/.\d+/g,c=>c[0].repeat(parseInt(c.slice(1),7)+3))
```

The following code is used to do the run-length encoding and packing:

```js
chars="",max=16;
[...uncompressed].map(c=>~chars.indexOf(c)?0:chars+=c);
base=max-chars.length;
chars+=[...Array(base).keys()].join``;
unpacked=uncompressed.replace(/(.)\1{2,}/g,c=>c[0]+(c.length-3).toString(base));
packed=unpacked.replace(/(.|\n){2}/g,s=> // Note: unpacked length must be even!
  String.fromCharCode(chars.indexOf(s[0])|(chars.indexOf(s[1])<<4)));
```

#### Huffman Coding, (Possible Future Improvement)

Certain characters occur much more than others, so a Huffman encoding (variable-length integers representing each character) could save some further bytes. However this will introduce a lot more complexity into the decompression algorithm, so aside from being a lot more work it may also cost more bytes to decompress it than it saves in the encoded string.

Comment: I tried using the same compression as I did for my Easter answer but that takes 421 bytes just to reproduce the string.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, 905 bytes

Whew.. The 12 hour clock killed my otherwise short (*ahum*) solution.
905 bytes to print 898 chars of ascii art yay

```
_=>(a=(d=Date)(c=new d(),z=O=>Math.abs(new d(a[3]+O)-c)).split` `)[1]=='Apr'&a[2]==20|~a[4].search(/(04|16):20/)?'0,0,2ca2o,0,10e,0,0,1eu9z4,0,22w,1ulajuo,0,bklxc,2zgg,i,120gdfk,8lc,1s1s,15,j0jf9c,7em8,tac,10,190zcw0,tm8w,ksk,hra0ia,mihog0,3aels,wy,iv8e15,b98u80,cvs1s,575,9fm71g,190zcw0,bg7vgg,1t4,148d4lu,121pblx,b9ea68,2b36,iv8hn5,9zleso,15kytz4,98cp,4fwpwk,zir9ud,1h9u3ln,11c6vb4,84kda8,kbuo05,b98u84,14possy,k9su6i,a26hwk,zvft34,kavrpc,1tn1j4,1r3jis,kamgao,a5bhq8,2b2q,beyt6x,j0y810,muhiww,9xl,a5b7s8,14npcwi,1bkfw1s,4ys,14lipw4,kalr6k,0,1aq,kalqzg,0,48m,2j6hqf,zik0zk,0,33mcjk,0,5'.split`,`.map(a=>('0'.repeat(32)+parseInt(a,36).toString(2)).substr(-32)).join``.match(/.{1,3}/g).map(a=>` .:\`|;'
`[parseInt(a,2)]).join``:~~((T=Math.min(z('/4/20'),z(` ${a[1]} ${++a[2]} 0:4:20`),z(' 4:20'),z(' 0:4:20'),z(' 16:20'),z(' 0:16:20'))/1000)/60)+` minutes and ${~~(T%60)} seconds left until your next hit.`
```

#### Ungolfed code

Note: The ungolfed code will not execute

```
function() {
    // (all vars here are actually global)
    var d = Date; // short reference to Date object
    var dateString = Date() // "Tue Apr 12 2016 20:13:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)"
    .split` `; // ["Tue", "Apr", "12", ...]
    var currentDate = new Date();
    dateDiff = function(toAppend) {
        return Math.abs( // no dates in the past
            new Date(dateString[3] + toAppend) // new Date('2016' + something)
            - currentDate // substract the current date. 
                          // Thanks JS for the datetime implementation
        );
    }

    if ((dateString[1] == 'Apr' & dateString[2] == 20) |
        ~dateString[4].search(/(04|16):20/)) { // if the time doesn't contain 04:20 or 
                                               // 16:20, this will return -1. ~-1 is 0 
                                               // and thus falsy
        alert(printAscii());
    } else {
        alert(printTimeLeft());
    }
}

function printAscii() {
    var magicString = '0,0,2ca2o,0,10e,0,0,1eu9z4,0,22w,1ulajuo,0,bklxc,2zgg,i,120gdfk,8lc,1s1s,15,j0jf9c,7em8,tac,10,190zcw0,tm8w,ksk,hra0ia,mihog0,3aels,wy,iv8e15,b98u80,cvs1s,575,9fm71g,190zcw0,bg7vgg,1t4,148d4lu,121pblx,b9ea68,2b36,iv8hn5,9zleso,15kytz4,98cp,4fwpwk,zir9ud,1h9u3ln,11c6vb4,84kda8,kbuo05,b98u84,14possy,k9su6i,a26hwk,zvft34,kavrpc,1tn1j4,1r3jis,kamgao,a5bhq8,2b2q,beyt6x,j0y810,muhiww,9xl,a5b7s8,14npcwi,1bkfw1s,4ys,14lipw4,kalr6k,0,1aq,kalqzg,0,48m,2j6hqf,zik0zk,0,33mcjk,0,5' // ;)
    var splitted = magicString.split`,`;
    var binarySequence = splitted.map(function(piece) {
        return ('0'.repeat(32) + // 000000000... this will be padded
            parseInt(a,36) // parseInt('190zcw0',36) -> 000000002722627584
            .toString(2) // -> 10100010010010000000000000000000
        ).substr(-32) // left pad binary sequence
    }).join``; // create one big binary sequence from several smaller
    var groupsOfThree = binarySequence.match(/.{1,3}/g);
    return groupsOfThree.map(function(three) {
        return ` .:\`|;'\n`[parseInt(a,2)]; // magic.. turn 010 into : etc
    }).join``; // create them blaze
}

function printTimeLeft() {
    // this is way longer than it should be.. probably
    var minimumTimeDifference = Math.min(
        dateDiff('/4/20'), // -> Difference between now and 2016/4/20 00:00:00
        dateDiff(' 4:20'), // 2016 04:20:00.. Sadly the 2016 is needed (i think)
        dateDiff(' 0:4:20'), // 2016 00:04:20
        dateDiff(' 16:20'), // Damn 12 hour clock :(
        dateDiff(' 0:16:20'),
        dateDiff(` ${dateString[1]} // 2016 Apr 
                   ${dateString[2]+1} // 2016 Apr 13 (12+1)
                   0:4:20` // Check the first occurrence of 4 minutes and 20 seconds 
                           // the next day
    )
    var timeInSeconds = minimumTimeDifference / 1000;
    return Math.floor(timeInSeconds) + // ~~ works like Math.floor
        ` minutes and ${Math.floor(timeInSeconds%60)} seconds left until your next hit.`;
}
```

#### Try it!

```js
f=
_=>(a=(d=Date)(c=new d(),z=O=>Math.abs(new d(a[3]+O)-c)).split` `)[1]=='Apr'&a[2]==20|~a[4].search(/(04|16):20/)?'0,0,2ca2o,0,10e,0,0,1eu9z4,0,22w,1ulajuo,0,bklxc,2zgg,i,120gdfk,8lc,1s1s,15,j0jf9c,7em8,tac,10,190zcw0,tm8w,ksk,hra0ia,mihog0,3aels,wy,iv8e15,b98u80,cvs1s,575,9fm71g,190zcw0,bg7vgg,1t4,148d4lu,121pblx,b9ea68,2b36,iv8hn5,9zleso,15kytz4,98cp,4fwpwk,zir9ud,1h9u3ln,11c6vb4,84kda8,kbuo05,b98u84,14possy,k9su6i,a26hwk,zvft34,kavrpc,1tn1j4,1r3jis,kamgao,a5bhq8,2b2q,beyt6x,j0y810,muhiww,9xl,a5b7s8,14npcwi,1bkfw1s,4ys,14lipw4,kalr6k,0,1aq,kalqzg,0,48m,2j6hqf,zik0zk,0,33mcjk,0,5'.split`,`.map(a=>('0'.repeat(32)+parseInt(a,36).toString(2)).substr(-32)).join``.match(/.{1,3}/g).map(a=>` .:\`|;'
`[parseInt(a,2)]).join``:~~((T=Math.min(z('/4/20'),z(` ${a[1]} ${++a[2]} 0:4:20`),z(' 4:20'),z(' 0:4:20'),z(' 16:20'),z(' 0:16:20'))/1000)/60)+` minutes and ${~~(T%60)} seconds left until your next hit.`

alert(f())
```

In the following code snippet you can set the date to test the ascii art

```js
day=prompt('Day?', 12);
month=prompt('Month?', 'Apr');
f=
_=>(a=(d=Date)(c=new d(),z=O=>Math.abs(new d(a[3]+O)-c)).split` `)[1]==month&a[2]==day|~a[4].search(/(04|16):20/)?'0,0,2ca2o,0,10e,0,0,1eu9z4,0,22w,1ulajuo,0,bklxc,2zgg,i,120gdfk,8lc,1s1s,15,j0jf9c,7em8,tac,10,190zcw0,tm8w,ksk,hra0ia,mihog0,3aels,wy,iv8e15,b98u80,cvs1s,575,9fm71g,190zcw0,bg7vgg,1t4,148d4lu,121pblx,b9ea68,2b36,iv8hn5,9zleso,15kytz4,98cp,4fwpwk,zir9ud,1h9u3ln,11c6vb4,84kda8,kbuo05,b98u84,14possy,k9su6i,a26hwk,zvft34,kavrpc,1tn1j4,1r3jis,kamgao,a5bhq8,2b2q,beyt6x,j0y810,muhiww,9xl,a5b7s8,14npcwi,1bkfw1s,4ys,14lipw4,kalr6k,0,1aq,kalqzg,0,48m,2j6hqf,zik0zk,0,33mcjk,0,5'.split`,`.map(a=>('0'.repeat(32)+parseInt(a,36).toString(2)).substr(-32)).join``.match(/.{1,3}/g).map(a=>` .:\`|;'
`[parseInt(a,2)]).join``:~~((T=Math.min(z('/4/20'),z(` ${a[1]} ${++a[2]} 0:4:20`),z(' 4:20'),z(' 0:4:20'),z(' 16:20'),z(' 0:16:20'))/1000)/60)+` minutes and ${~~(T%60)} seconds left until your next hit.`

alert(f())
```

Comment: I think an invalid time like `15:16:20` will be a match on your regex and accidentally display the magic string?

Comment: @KevinLau Dang, you're right. Will fix that tomorrow..

Comment: I don't think `()` are necessary for the `date` constructor: `c=new d(), ...` can  become just `c=new d, ...`